# Problems in detecting pendrive

Tags: ubuntu, usb, usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-12.04

I have this problems when I insert my pendrive. It is very slow in detecting it (3.0 and 2.0 port). I'm using uBuntu 12.04.3 x64. It requires me to wait for minutes to finally detect it. Is there any workaround with this issue?

Comment: Does this USB drive work well under other OS like Windows or Mac? You may want to reformat your pendrive under Linux using `gparted`

Comment: The pen drive works well in windows. It took me 7 minutes to detect it. I just format the pen drive after it detected using right click->format. Not only my pen drive but external hard drive too. After formatting the pen drive it's still requires minutes to detect.